# Как выяснить что данные в JSON обновились

Tags: android

Есть JSON файл радио, в котором при окончании и начале проигрывания новой композиции обновляется запись. Как узнать что данные в JSON Файле обновились? Как лучше это сделать?

Comment: Это понятно.. Дело в том, что json находится на сервере, куда я доступа не имею у меня есть только ссылка на json. И не могу знать допустим когда песня закончилась и запись в json изменилась.   Если через 3-5 секунд каждый раз парсить json и выводить в TextView данные правильно ли это будет с точки зрения ресурсов? Или есть получше вариант?

Comment: Изменила. Вы правы, некорректно оформила вопрос(

Comment: Этот JSON - это какой то плейлист, который скачивается локально и по нему потом получают треки или при каждой последующей композиции скачивается новый JSON? Как вообще устроен весь механизм проигрывания и работа с эти JSON? нужно больше подробностей.

Comment: Файл содержит данные типа {
      "mount": "/armenian.mp3",
      "name": "Армянское радио",
      "listeners": "0",
      "title": "Название Трека",
      "url": "http://site.ru/armenian.mp3"
    }

Из него просто берется title и выводится в TextView когда играет радио по соответствующему URL

Comment: Указанный Вами JSON очевидно идёт как Metadata в потоке вещания.

Comment: Возможно) так как понять что данные изменились?

Comment: @Kroshka Это называется IcyStreamMeta. На затравку http://uniqueculture.net/2010/11/stream-metadata-plain-java/

Comment: А где там указать мой JSON файл?

Comment: json файл ? Он у Вас точно именно как отдельный идёт не зависимо от потока вещания?

Comment: У меня есть ссылка на JSON файл в котором по окончании песни изменяется название Песни. Так вот мне нужно понимать когда данные изменились в этом JSON?

Comment: @Kroshka я ппримерно представляю, про какой JSON Вы говорите. Это icecast умеет. Он действительно обновляется при смене Metadata. Но событие изменения этой Metadata не генерируется в файле, он статичен на протяжении всей песни, и событий в нём взять неоткуда, если не читать каждую секунду. Событие появляется непосредственно в  IcyStreamMeta, и в идеале нужно чиатать именно оттуда.

Comment: Не очень поняла что мне нужно в итоге сделать( я тот класс просмотрела, там в первом классе идет вроде как разбор потока что ли, а во втором классе на вход подается сам поток если я правильно поняла.. Можете ли вы для моего случая небольшой примерчик написать? У меня JSON грузится отсюда https://site.ru/info.json

Comment: Я пока сделала просто чтобы каждые две секунды парсил JSON Файл. С точки зрения ресурсов системы не затратно ли это, учитывая что JSON файл не очень большой?

Comment: Это нормально, радио играет через интернет, юзер это понимает, джсон файл вашего размера можно сказать что ничего не весит, в идеале делайте получение джсон-а и парсинг не в UI потоке и все будет нормально.

Comment: Поняла. Спасибо.